# List of medical synonyms for information retrieval, elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym, medical

I am looking for a list of medical synonyms to use at token filter stage in elastic search (it will read a synonyms.txt file) basically equivalent to this one in emerse search engine:

https://project-emerse.org/synonyms.html

However the $2500 annual licencing for academic purposes is beyond my means ( I am conducting a 16 week MSc research project).

Are there more affordable/free sources of such lists?

Comment: From the provided link it seems get the list of synonyms is free ?

Comment: No, they offer some data sets, formatted to work with Emerse for free. But "EMERSE Synonyms Collection" (bottom of the page) is only available under licence: "The EMERSE Synonyms list is available for academic use in applications, services and other use cases. Please note, this license is for academic research applications only. Current fees included $2,500 for the first year, followed by $500 for each subsequent year. Please use the contact link above to initiate a licensing discussion."

Comment: Ah indeed my bad. I feel this might be also worth asking this question on other So communities focused on health. You might not have the good audience here.